# Error with add_censor_mark() in ggsurvfit package when used with weighted survival data

Tags: ggsurvfit

Wanted to add censor mark to the weighted KM curves but encountered error - any work around or solutions?

```
fit <- survfit2(Surv(survival_time, event) ~ tx, data = ttd, weights = wt01)

fit %>%
  ggsurvfit()+
  add_risktable(
  risktable_stats =
    c("{round(n.risk,1)}", "{round(cum.event,1)}", "{round(cum.censor,1)}"),
  stats_label = c("At Risk", "Cum. Events", "Cum. Censor"),
  times=seq(0,36,3))+
   add_quantile(y_value = 0.5, linetype = "dotted", color = "grey30", linewidth = 0.8) +
  add_censor_mark()
```

Error received was

Error in `ggplot2::geom_point()` at rlang/R/eval.R:195:3:
! Problem while computing layer data.
ℹ Error occurred in the 4th layer.
Caused by error in `tidyr::uncount()`:
! Can't convert from `weights`  to  due to loss of precision.

Thanks!
Sophia

Tried with the above code but encountered error.